# Is there an alternative for Drupal in .Net?

Tags: .net, rest, content-management-system

I need a CMS site in .Net that will support Restful API as well.

Basically my client needs a CMS web site that will allow them to upload product details and then those details should be exposed via a REST api so that an android app can make use of these product details.

Any suggestions on what I can use?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076897/net-cms-choice-for-working-with-external-data

Comment: Thanks I will take a looksy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most famous **ASP.NET CMS** is **Umbraco**:

https://umbraco.com/

As Muhammedh pointed out in a comment, **Umbraco** also supports REST API:

https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Implementation/Rest-Api/

Comment: Thanks. does it support REST api?

Comment: @Muhammedh being in ASP.NET you can add your custom API as normal ASP.NET Web API (Maybe in a separate project and interact with it).

Comment: found this out :)  https://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Implementation/Rest-Api/